# Adding -fvisibility=hidden after compilation

Tags: linux, gcc, ld

I am building a shared object (.so), and I am linking it against a third party static library.  In an ideal world, that third party library would have been compiled with `-fvisibility=hidden` - but it hasn't been.

Is there a way to avoid including the symbols defined by that static library in the global symbols exported by the dynamic library?

(I am using gcc on the linux platform if it matters)

Comment: take a look at `strip`

Comment: I suppose I could write a script which runs `nm` on the .a file to find all the symbols defined by it, and uses `strip --strip-symbol=symbol1 ...` to remove them all from the .so.  Is that what you meant @MichałWalenciak?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `strip` and its full capabilities but generally speaking that's what I ment.

Answer (score 0):

You can control symbols that get exported via `-Wl,--version-script=<version-script>`. Version script would look like

```
LIBMYLIB_1.0 {
  global:
    libmylib_foo; libmylib_bar;

  local:
    *;
};
```

(library symbols will get filtered in `local` section).

Note that you should still use hidden visibility wherever possible (even if you enable version scripts) as it allows compiler to optimize better.